# Find areas to output in pdf file

Tags: ruby, pdf, pattern-recognition

Problem: I have a scanned version of some tax report (e.g. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3TmJsb1vYhqclFFendvTlRoV28/edit?usp=sharing ), and I must fill it programmly. So, it`s needed to find empty areas and put to it some values in program.
Now I see only one solution - manually find coordinates of these empty areas, code it to program, and output values to these coordinates.
Is it possible to programmly find coordinates (may be by some pattern recognition or something else) of empty areas? May be use of some Ruby tools (e.g. Prawn) ?

Comment: It would be simpler if the file were not an image captured in a PDF but actually the form blocks in a PDF.

Comment: There are tools that try to recognize paper form field areas in scans but their results should be checked manually before use. I would advice instead that you add PDF form fields to the PDF template and later fill them programmatically by name. That being said your example text report is **not** scanned (or if it is scanned, it has been very well post-processed)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there isn't complete automatic solution. I've solved this problem by searching areas to input, store its coordinates and then output to these areas